# target css for opera: fix resize with bottom:0

Tags: css, resize, opera

I have an html windows demo here: dlml.org/gargoyle/windowsdemo.html

Works for all browsers except opera, which doesn't resize properly with bottom:0 (confirmed here: http://dev.opera.com/forums/topic/562551).

I've substituted top:0 bottom:0 with height:100% here and there, and that helps, but that's not possible in all situations.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: What version of Opera do you need to support? It works fine in Opera 11.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: table;` properties in CSS

Comment: It's tempting, but I still get more than 20% of my users on IE 7 (which I read has problems with display:table), whereas 0.33% are opera. Also I have splitters between pairs of cells, to allow users to set arbitrary boundaries. Not really a table thing. Still, I'll keep it in mind and experiment a bit. Thanks for the feedback.